# How to read integer from a text file on multiple lines in MIPS

Tags: assembly, mips

I have a file text with content likes below. How I can read and convert them to integer in MIPS

```
5
12 17 87 35 98
```

and here is my code to read file

```
.data
fileName: .asciiz "C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\input.txt"
newline : .asciiz "\n"
buffer: .space 1024
.text
.globl main
main:
    # open file
    li $v0,13
    la $a0,fileName
    li $a1,0
    li $a2,0
    syscall
    move $s0,$v0

    # read file
    li $v0,14
    move $a0,$s0
    la $a1,buffer
    li $a2,1024
    syscall

    # print buffer
    li $v0,4
    la $a0,buffer
    syscall
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Homework, I guess, so no complete code.

There's no built-in syscall for reading ints from a file. So you'd have to read it as a string into a data buffer and convert ASCII characters to ints.

The algorithm is:

- initialize the final number to zero
- go through the string of digits from the beginning to the end
- convert the current digit character to a number (subtract 0x30)
- multiply the current value of final number by 10, add the current digit
- move to the next character, until you hit a nondigit

Take a look at the ASCII code table to see the character codes of digits. For step two, use one of the registers as a pointer: initialize to the address of buffer, use `lb` to read the current digit from it, then increment as you go.

Does that help?